# How can I silently make a nested class aware of it's outer class (by putting all the required code in parent or metaclass)?

Tags: python-3.x, class, enums, abstraction, metaclass

I have made a symbol class that helps me to make symbolic constants by using metaclasses

```
>>> class SymbolClass(type):
    def __repr__(self): return self.__name__

>>> class Symbol(metaclass=SymbolClass): pass

>>> class Spam(Symbol) : pass

>>> class Egg(Symbol) : pass

>>> class Banana(Symbol) : pass

>>> mydict = {Egg:"Where is the bacon", Banana:(2, 3, 4)}

>>> mydict
{Egg: 'Where is the bacon', Banana: (2, 3, 4)}
```

However, If I want to use it for enumerations by nesting such symbols in an outer class, I will need a way to make the symbol inner classes aware of their outer class. With the current implementation, here is what happens :

```
>>> class Animal:
        class Dog(Symbol): pass
        class Cat(Symbol): pass

>>> print(repr(Animal.Dog))
Dog
```

It would be OK to get this reply from printing `str(Animal.Dog)`, but when printing `repr(Animal.Dog)`, I'd like to get `Animal.Dog`.

So, How could I make the nested `Animal.Dog` and `Animal.Cat` classes, aware of their outer `Animal` class, but without complicating their declaration. I want to have all the needed code, hidden in the super classes (`Symbol` or `Animal`'s superclass), or their metaclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__qualname__` in contrast with name includes the information about enclosing classes or functions:

```
In [13]: class Symbol(type):
    ...:     def __repr__(cls):
    ...:         return cls.__qualname__
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [14]: class Dog(metaclass=Symbol): pass

In [15]: Dog
Out[15]: Dog

In [16]: class Animal:
    ...:     class Dog(metaclass=Symbol): pass
    ...: 

In [17]: Animal.Dog
Out[17]: Animal.Dog
```

Of course, if you really want to use Enums, Python's `enum.Enum`can cover a wide number of use cases. Sometimes I just find it overkill, and use some simpler ad-hoc things, but once you are resorting to a custom metaclass, that is no longer "simpler", and you likely will have some corner cases ahead that enum has already solved.

## Really getting information about the enclosing class

Now, regardless of Enums, if one wants to use a metaclass and have information about the enclosing class body - as in the title of this question, the thing is trickier. For inside a class body definition, the variables in the class body itself are the local variables, and the global variables point to the module globals: there is no equivalent of `nonlocal` as when the enclosing scope is a function.

If an object that is set as a class attribute needs information about its owner class, Python implements the powerful [*descriptor procotol*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), used by the language built-in `property`. All you need is to have a `__get__` method defined in your object's class, and take note of the owners attributes: no metaclasses needed:

```
In [56]: class Symbol: # not a metaclass
    ...:     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    ...:         self.owner = owner
    ...:         return self
    ...:     def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
    ...:         self.name = name
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         return f"{self.owner.__name__}.{self.name}"
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [57]: class Animal:
    ...:     Dog = Symbol()
    ...: 

In [58]: Animal.Dog
Out[58]: Animal.Dog
```

Now, if one wants information on the enclosing scope at a nested class creation time,  it is feasible, but one needs to introspect the stack in the metaclass' `__new__` and find if `locals` in the enclosing scope is the body of another class. A strong hint of it is if it will have  `__module__` and `__qualname__` keys defined. Then you have access to the enclosing class namespace, but...the enclosing class itself does not exist yet:

```
In [40]: import inspect

In [41]: class M(type):
    ...:     def __new__(mcls, name, bases, ns, **kw):
    ...:         enclosing_frame = inspect.stack()[1].frame
    ...:         print (enclosing_frame.f_locals)
    ...:         return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, ns, **kw)
    ...: 

In [42]: class A:
    ...:     class B(metaclass=M): pass
    ...: 
{'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'A'}
```

So, if all that is wanted is the enclosing class `__name__`, one can just use `__qualname__` and be done with it. But if all one wanted was the name, `__qualname__` itself is already set on the nested class namespace.

If one wants a valid reference to the `__class__` itself, it is not possible when the nested class itself is created, because the outer class does not exist at this point: it will only be created at the end of the definition of its own body, of course.

Fortunately, the descriptor mechanism will work if the attribute is a class, and the `__set_name__` special method is defined in its metaclass:

```
In [51]: class Symbol(type):
    ...:     def __set_name__(cls, owner, name):
    ...:         assert name == cls.__name__
    ...:         cls.owner = owner
             # it turns out __get__ is not needed for  __set_name__ to work
    ...:     #def __get__(cls, instance, owner):
    ...:         # needed so the attribute is recognized as a descriptor (? - actually: to be checked)
    ...:     #    return cls
    ...:     def __repr__(cls):
    ...:         return f"{cls.owner.__name__}.{cls.__name__}"
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [52]: class Animal:
    ...:     class Dog(metaclass=Symbol): pass
    ...: 

In [53]: Animal.Dog
Out[53]: Animal.Dog
```

Again: this last part of the question is just here for people wanting to get a reference to the outer class for other purposes than getting the name. Now, check that the descriptor protocol, with the `__get__` method can provide such information without the need for a metaclass at all.

Comment: I like solutions which help master the language without requiring complicated libraries. This is exactly whit I was looking for, and I feared it was going to be much much more complicated. Thank you.

Comment: Note that Ethan from the other answer is the author of Python Enum itself (the one enclosed in the stdlib), and undestanding it is an important step in mastering the language as well;

Comment: The point is that by using all made libraries, i won't make the skilsl to write one by myself, and that's something you need to build by increasing complexity.

Comment: Very nice answer.  The only change I would make is the description of `__set_name__` -- it is run when `super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, ns, **kw)` is called, so `__set_name__` has access to the (usually) complete parent class -- "usually" because if the metaclass does stuff after the `__new__(mcls, ...)` call then that part will not have been completed yet.  I had to rewrite the 3.11 `EnumMeta.__new__` so that `__set_name__` and `__init_subclass__` would be working with a complete Enum (meaning all members present).

Comment: Indeed, there is no 'callback' to be run after the metaclass `__init__` takes place - the fatc that `type.__new__` does a lot of things and does not use any slots gets in the way of some meta-programming.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `Animal` inherit from `Enum`:

```
from enum import Enum

class Animal(Enum):
    class Dog(Symbol): pass
    class Cat(Symbol): pass

>>> print(repr(Animal.Dog))
<Animal.Dog: Dog>

>>> print(Animal.Dog)
Animal.Dog
```

If you want different `str()`s and `repr()`s you need to define them:

```
class Animal(Enum):
    #
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s.%s" % (self.__class__.__name__, self._name_)
    #
    def __str__(self):
        return self._name_
    #
    class Dog(Symbol): pass
    class Cat(Symbol): pass
```